# What does it mean if it shows a question mark over the Steam Cloud icon?

Tags: steam, steam-cloud

Looking at my games in List View, I noticed that it shows a question mark over some of them with whether or not they support the Steam Cloud.

[image: The normal icon and the one with a question mark]

What does this mean?

Comment: I don't know what causes it, but I can get it to go away if I turn cloud support for the game off and then back on again...  I think it has something to do with whether or not Steam has the latest data from your "cloud saves" or not, which would mean that loading the game would likely cause the ? to go away.

Comment: @agent86: Yeah, it seems to go away when it syncs next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the ? means that Steam isn't sure if it's synced with the Steam Cloud.  When you launch the game, or if you toggle cloud support for a game, the icon turns from the "question mark" to just a cloud icon.  I tested this with a couple of games in my library, and this seemed to be a pattern.  I can't find any Steam FAQs on this topic, so this is more of an educated guess backed up by some research.

I presume that on launch, Steam checks in with the cloud servers to see if there's any updated information to sync, and then it "knows" that the data is properly synchronized.  At other times, it's possible that it has changed since the last time Steam checked, so it shows the question mark.